# Ошибка SmartGWT (А у вас ?)

Tags: smartgwt, java

Долго искал в чем дело, минимизировал программу и вот что получилось:

```
package ru.ig.thdr.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.ButtonItem;

public class Thdr implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        System.out.println("Start");
        ButtonItem bi = new ButtonItem("Button Item");
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

**Не работает** выдает трэйс (зараза не пастится из Eclipse), смысл такой:

```
Unable to load module entry point ... 
java.lang.AssertionError: Invalid FormItem name. Cannot use spaces in FormItem name
```

Валится на new ButtonItem("Button Item");. Ошибка понятна (**пробел в имени**) для FormItem .

Вопрос собственно такой - **это во всех версиях такая фигня** или мне такая попала ?
(Smart GWT 2.5)

*Собственно меня это так заело, поскольку (сам дурак) сообщение об ошибке невнимательно прочитал и дооолго искал ее в других местах.*

Еще вопросик - каким html тегом (или Unicode символ) можно вставить "пробел" (символ, который изображается, как пробел) ?

```
<sp> и <nbsp>
```

не работают.

Comment: Ответ простой: ButtonItem("int-name","А это в кнопке нарисуем")

Котяра молодец.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, это не проблема, а скорее, недопонимание логики работы. *Вы путаете внутреннее обозначение `name` и `label`.* `label` - это то, что показывается конечному пользователю приложения, а `name` - что-то вроде некоторого внутреннего **алиаса**.

Соответственно, нужно изменять `label`, у которого, разумеется, *нет ограничений на использование пробелов*, а `name` задавать некоторым образом, соответствующим внутренней конвенции `SmartGWT`.

Подробнее можно прочитать [**здесь.**](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=9154)

Comment: Именно так.

Comment: Нет. В данном случае (не знаю что и как правильно называть) для объекта типа ButtonItem , который надо паковать в ячейку DynamicForm понятие label отсутствует. name здесь соответствует тому, что Вы называете label, **именно оно (которое в скобочках) при new ButtonItem** показывается зрителю. Менять его можно вызывая метод .setName(String).  То, что Вы подразумеваете  под name (**алиас**)(внутренний идентификатор) получаем по getID(). ***В данном случае я не путаю*** 

Кстати, Вы что решили что я пытаюсь таким вызовом установить ID ???

**Вопрос о другом** как изобразить пробел. **Он остался**

Comment: @avp Либо у вас какая-то косячная ревизия `SmartGWT`, либо я чего-то не знаю. В документации [**здесь**][1] указано, что конструктор принимает `name` и еще *(во втором варианте)* `title`.

[1]: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/ButtonItem.html

Comment: Да @Котик_хочет_кушать , Вы правы. Сам только что посмотрел на еще одну форму конструктора. Просто для Button-s во всех их видах этот первый аргумент рисуется где надо, вот и вводит в заблуждение. И насчет ID я погорячился. 

В общем плюсую и закрываю.